# Why does my Float32List not get passed to a vec4 in my shader as expected? vec2 works fine

Tags: dart, glsl, webgl, shader

I'm pretty new to Dart, WebGL, GLSL; but I've got some simple code rendering some sprites to the screen. While trying to add support for rendering parts of textures (to support sprite sheets), I came across some strange behaviour that I can't figure out (I don't think it's a bug, I think I'm misunderstanding; yet I can't figure it out!).

I've managed to strip the code to something really simple, where I can switch between it working and not; with the following lines in my shader:

```c
vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord * aTextureRect.xy / aTextureFullSize; // WORKS FINE
vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord * aTextureRect.zw / aTextureFullSize; // RENDERS BLANK SQUARE
```

Note the only difference between these lines is using `.xy` vs `.zw`.

The `aTextureRect` attribute is declared like this:

```c
attribute vec4 aTextureRect;
```

I'm setting it like this:

```c
aTextureRect = _gl.getAttribLocation(program, "aTextureRect");
_gl.vertexAttrib2fv(shader.aTextureRect, new Float32List.fromList([128.0, 128.0, 128.0, 128.0]));
```

Note that I'm setting all 4 floats to the same value.

It seems that only the first two parts of my `vec4` are being set (`x` and `y`); neither of the other two are 128 (I confirmed this by swapping them in in place of the `y` individually, and nothing renders for either).

This is the first `vec4` I've used in my shader; all other attributes are `vec2`, so I presume there's something different with how this works; but I'm struggling to figure out what!

Answer (score 1):

Oh man, I've been staring at the screen too long!

```c
_gl.vertexAttrib2fv(shader.aTextureRect, new Float32List.fromList([128.0, 128.0, 128.0, 128.0]));
                ^
```

Should've been

```c
_gl.vertexAttrib4fv(shader.aTextureRect, new Float32List.fromList([128.0, 128.0, 128.0, 128.0]));
                ^
```

At least WebGL crashed and informed me I was passing more data than expected, eh? </sarcasm>